# Notation: Dot over a set

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

In Steenrod's "Cohomology Operations" (1962, p. 3) I found the notation $\overset{\cdot}{I} $. What does this mean? 
Something like the boundary?

The book is written with a typewriter.

Comment: I do not have the book, but using a small circle above the set is a usual notation for interior. If it is written with a typewriter, they might have replaced the circle with a dot.

Comment: I also thought that first, but it makes not really sense.

Comment: You can download it https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/steenrod-epstein.pdf

Comment: It sometimes denotes the interior, sometimes it denotes the boundary. In Steenrod probably the boundary: If $I=[0,1]$ then I guess $\dot I=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you! You confirm my guess! I would expect it as an answer.